# proper retract of a limit group

Tags: gr.group-theory

A finitely generated group $G$ is called  *limit group* if, for any finite subset $S\subset G$, there exists a homomorphism $f:G\to F$ (where $F$ is a free group of finite rank) so that the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is injective.

Let $H$ be a *proper retract* of $G$, i.e., a subgroup of $H\lneq G$ for which there exists a homomorphism $r:G\to H$ such that $r(h)=h$, for all $h\in H$.

By [Louder's theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/geometry-and-topology/volume-16/issue-1/Krull-dimension-for-limit-groups/10.2140/gt.2012.16.219.full), there is a function $D(n)$ such that if $F_n \to L_1 \to \cdots \to L_k$ is a sequence of proper epimorphism of limit groups, where $F_n$ is a free group with $n$-generator, then $k\leq D(n)$. Let $G$ be a limit group. In particular, take $L_1$ equal to $G$ which is a finitely presented (as a limit group) then there exists an integer $k_G$ such that for every sequence with proper retrctions $G=L_1 \to G_2 \to \cdots \to G_k$, we have $k\leq k_G$. If $H$ is a proper retract of a limit group $G$, then is $k_H \lneq k_G$?

Comment: Once more, your question is ill-posed. The way you "define" $k_G$ is not unique, and you can increase arbitrarily the value of $k_G$ for one given $G$. So, for an arbitrary such assignment $G\mapsto k_G$, the answer is clearly "no". However, if you choose $k_G$ as the largest length of a chain of proper limit quotients of $G$, then the answer isa trivial yes.

Comment: @YCor That's right. You are right. What do you mean by proper limit quotients of $G$? You mean a sequence $G=G_0 \twoheadrightarrow‎ G_1 \twoheadrightarrow‎ \cdots \twoheadrightarrow‎ G_k$ of proper epimorphisms of limits groups $G_i$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Dear @YCor , Is there any relation between $k_G$ and rank $F$? I mean can we write $k_G$ in terms of other group properties of limit group $G$?

Comment: @Mahtab: it's not possible to extract an exact formula for $k_G$ from Louder's proof. With some work one might be able to write down an explicit upper bound from Louder's proof, but it would be huge.

Comment: In any case, @YCor has pointed out that the answer to your question, properly formulated, is trivially "yes". I suggest you write it up as an answer and accept it (unless YCor wants to do it himself).

Comment: It's not really a yes or no. There's a problem in formulation as "there exist $a$ and $b$ such that blablah; is it true that $a\le b$" since $a,b$ are not uniquely defined by blablah. Unfortunately OP hasn't taken this into account and the post is still ambiguous.

Comment: @YCor: when the OP rights "you are right", I think they mean that the definition you propose is correct. I don't think Louder gives an explicit definition in his paper, but your definition is certainly what he has in mind.

Comment: @HJRW Ah OK, thanks. Note that the definition differs if one allows free abelian groups among quotients and I don't know if it's better or not to include them.

Comment: @YCor: why wouldn’t you?